# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): respo.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, use-effect

I'm a beginner in React and stuck with some problem. Getting an issue Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): respo.json is not a function.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const { monster, setMonster } = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const respo = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      const resp = await respo.data;
      setMonster({ monster: [...resp] });
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [monster]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{console.log(monster)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you give a screenshot of your respo object ?

Comment: it should be respo.data instead of resp.json()

Answer (score 3):

[image]Use respo.data instead :

Your response has a data key which you need to fetch.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [monster,setMonster]=useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchData() {
     const respo=await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
     const resp=await respo.data;
     setMonster({monster:[...respo]});

    }

      fetchData();
},[]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{console.log(monster)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Working code : https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-platform-1itbi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Now I'm getting and error as setMonster is not a function. Please find the screenshot above

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

1. `const {monster,setMonster}=useState([]);`

This should be:

```
const [monster,setMonster] = useState([]);
```

2. `const resp = await respo.data;`

This should be:

```
const resp = respo.data;
```

`respo.data` is not a promise, but already the result of the api.

Note:

To update `monster`, you have to call `setMonster(resp)` not `setMonster({ monster: resp })`

Comment: updated my answer, https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-gates-7xfjp?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

How about just using get/then instead of async/await?

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => {
            setMonster({
                monster:[...response.data]
            });
        });
    }
},[monster]);
```